# io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler.buildApplicationContext exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, micronaut

I have this aws lambda function in micronaut with **MicronautRequestHandler**,
when I add one dependency with utils and commons and test with http default of micronaut works correctly, but when run with SAM, MicronautLambdaTest or deploy in AWS I have this error:

*Bean definition [io.micronaut.http.server.netty.jackson.JsonHttpContentSubscriberFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.jackson.databind.JacksonDatabindMapper]

Message: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module Unable to get public no-arg constructor*

Here all error log:

```
Bean definition [io.micronaut.http.server.netty.jackson.JsonHttpContentSubscriberFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.jackson.databind.JacksonDatabindMapper]

Message: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module Unable to get public no-arg constructor
Path Taken: new JsonHttpContentSubscriberFactory(JsonMapper jsonMapper,HttpServerConfiguration httpServerConfiguration) --> new JsonHttpContentSubscriberFactory([JsonMapper jsonMapper],HttpServerConfiguration httpServerConfiguration) --> new JacksonDatabindMapper([ObjectMapper objectMapper])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [io.micronaut.http.server.netty.jackson.JsonHttpContentSubscriberFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.jackson.databind.JacksonDatabindMapper]

Message: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module Unable to get public no-arg constructor
Path Taken: new JsonHttpContentSubscriberFactory(JsonMapper jsonMapper,HttpServerConfiguration httpServerConfiguration) --> new JsonHttpContentSubscriberFactory([JsonMapper jsonMapper],HttpServerConfiguration httpServerConfiguration) --> new JacksonDatabindMapper([ObjectMapper objectMapper])
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1921)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:245)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:3326)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.finalizeConfiguration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3684)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:341)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:190)
    at app//io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.startApplicationContext(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:433)
    at app//io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.beforeClass(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:314)
    at app//io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension.beforeAll(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:83)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$12(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:211)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@11.0.16.1/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base@11.0.16.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.16.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base@11.0.16.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@11.0.16.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.jackson.databind.JacksonDatabindMapper]

Message: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module Unable to get public no-arg constructor
Path Taken: new JsonHttpContentSubscriberFactory(JsonMapper jsonMapper,HttpServerConfiguration httpServerConfiguration) --> new JsonHttpContentSubscriberFactory([JsonMapper jsonMapper],HttpServerConfiguration httpServerConfiguration) --> new JacksonDatabindMapper([ObjectMapper objectMapper])
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2367)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:66)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2065)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1297)
    at app//io.micronaut.jackson.databind.$JacksonDatabindMapper$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:66)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2065)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1297)
    at app//io.micronaut.http.server.netty.jackson.$JsonHttpContentSubscriberFactory$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.loadContextScopeBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2746)
    at app//io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1915)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:673)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1233)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1265)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1300)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1385)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findModules(ObjectMapper.java:1105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findModules(ObjectMapper.java:1089)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findAndRegisterModules(ObjectMapper.java:1139)
    at io.micronaut.jackson.ObjectMapperFactory.objectMapper(ObjectMapperFactory.java:120)
    at io.micronaut.jackson.$ObjectMapperFactory$ObjectMapper1$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/Mapping
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:660)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:657)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:668)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.spi.Mapping
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 117 more
```

In the dependency pom, but i no have access to code, and I need to use it per customer requirements.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

My gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-jackson-databind")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    //implementation("io.micronaut.beanvalidation:micronaut-hibernate-validator")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-jdbc")
    runtimeOnly group: 'io.micronaut', name: 'micronaut-http-server-netty', version: '3.6.3'
    implementation group: 'io.projectreactor.netty', name: 'reactor-netty', version: '1.0.22'
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    implementation group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'


    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:3.11.0'
    runtimeOnly 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:1.5.1'
    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws-api-proxy")
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager', version: '1.12.305'
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws-test")

    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-xml', version: '2.13.4'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.13.1'

    implementation('org.springframework:spring-webflux:5.3.23')

}
```

**Any advice or something I can do from the parent project?**

Comment: I don't know what was causing this issue (probably dependencies versions mismatch), but as a workaround, I've replaced `.findAndRegisterModules()` with `.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module())` plus all other modules added explicitly. Yes, it was Hibernate5 in my case.